# Xcode 6 - Set Active Configuration?

Tags: xcode, configuration, build, xcode6

I wonder where to set the "active" build configuration ( f.e. debug / release )
in **XCode 6** !?!

It seems not to be like it was in XCode 4 ...

does anyone know ?

thanks in advance,
Matthias :)

Comment: please, we need more description of problem. Take a look to ref about How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

In XCode 5 it was shifted into "Schemes", and available as part of the device build selection in the project main window run gadget thingies (top left).

In XCode 6, now you select Schemes from the normal menu's under Product -> Scheme.

An appstore build is an Archive build, that is submitted from the Organizer.